# How can I change the title of a ProgressMonitor in Java?

Tags: title, progressmonitor

ProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new ProgressMonitor(frame, "", "", 0, 100);

- progressMonitor.setProgress(0);
- ...
- progressMonitor.setProgress(100);

This works fine for me, but now I want to change the title of this progress monitor. Currently its "Progress...".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the title of the dialog window through the UIManager:

```java
String title = "Foobar";
UIManager.put("ProgressMonitor.progressText", title);
ProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new ProgressMonitor(frame, "", "", 0, 100);
...
```

---

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
monitor.beginTask("Running Job..", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
monitor.beginTask("Job #1");
```

But I don't believe the actual title of the box can change.